# how to dynamically change textview location?

Tags: java, android, xml, seekbar

I have a textview that shows the value of a seeker bar. I want to display that textview on top of the scrubber/slider as it is pulled left and right by the user.
What code do I need to do this?

```
    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekervalue);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194730/how-to-place-textview-using-x-y-position#answer-14194820

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `TextView.setX(float X)` (and if you need vertical movement) `TextView.setY(float Y)` inside your `onProgressChanged` method.

Just adjust the values depending on what you want.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        SeekBar sb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        final float startpos=tv.getX();
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                tv.setX(startpos+progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show how to make it move relative to the slider?

Comment: Will do, but you'll have to give me a while, as I'm a bit busy right now.

Comment: sure, no problem. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, it's done, I took a break and did it in a minute :), if you have any doubt tell me.