# How to set x and y values of TextView in Android Studio Programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to set a random value for textview of x and y together in 1 forloop.

I have a function

`fun createTextView(text: String, index: Int): TextView`

and on another function, I am using a for loop to create the TextView based on number of words in a list.

```
       val words = arrayListOf("abc","def","ghi")

       for ((wordIndex, i) in words.withIndex()){
            createTextView(i,wordIndex).x = some random number
        }
```

From this loop, I can only set either x or y value for my textview. How do I make it such that I can set both x and y value inside my for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place textview using x,y position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194730/how-to-place-textview-using-x-y-position)

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the return value in a variable and do it like this.

```
   val words = arrayListOf("abc","def","ghi")

   for ((wordIndex, i) in words.withIndex()){
      val textView = createTextView(i, wordIndex)
      textView.x = some random number
      textView.y = some random number
    }
```

Comment: Hello, just a follow up, how do I access textView I created in this for loop? let's say I want to change the text of one of the textViews?

Comment: The scope of the textView variable is inside the for loop so you can only access it inside the for-loop. Technically you can store the text views in a global array and change it but it will be messy.